# Proximity Graph in python

Tags: python, r, graph

I'm relatively new to Python coding (I'm switching from R mostly due to running time speed) and I'm trying to figure out how to code a proximity graph.

That is suppose i have an array of evenly-spaced points in d-dimensional Euclidean space, these will be my nodes.  I want to make these into an undirected graph by connecting two points if and only if they lie within e apart. How can I encode this functionally with parameters:

- n: spacing between two points on the same axis
- d: dimension of R^d
- e: maximum distance allowed for an edge to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/) library has [much of the functionality you need](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/generation.html). So you could do something like this, assuming you have `numpy` and `graph-tool`:

```
coords = numpy.meshgrid(*(numpy.linspace(0, (n-1)*delta, n) for i in range(d)))
# coords is a Python list of numpy arrays
coords = [c.flatten() for c in coords]
# now coords is a Python list of 1-d numpy arrays
coords = numpy.array(coords).transpose()
# now coords is a numpy array, one row per point
g = graph_tool.generation.geometric_graph(coords, e*(1+1e-9))
```

The silly `e*(1+1e-9)` thing is because your criterion is "distance <= e" and `geometric_graph`'s criterion is "distance < e".

There's a parameter called `delta` that you didn't mention because I think your description of parameter `n` is doing duty for two params (spacing between points, and number of points).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to install the package on Unbuntu 15.04, do you know a good how too link? (I'm entirely new to Python and am an R user by training)

Comment: All I can offer is https://graph-tool.skewed.de/download which has rather terse instructions for building it by hand and for installing via Ubuntu's package system. (For the latter, note that there's a box with extra instructions for 14.04 and 15.04.)

Comment: No worries, usually the most difficult lessons teach the most :)

Answer (score 1):

This bit of code should work, although it certainly isn't the most efficient. It will go through each node and check its distance to all the other nodes (that haven't already compared to it). If that distance is less than your value `e` then the corresponding value in the connected matrix is set to one. Zero indicates two nodes are not connected.

In this code I'm assuming that your `nodeList` is a list of cartesian coordinates of the form `nodeList = [[x1,y1,...],[x2,y2,...],...[xN,yN,...]]`. I also assume you have some function called `calcDistance` which returns the euclidean distance between two cartesian coordinates. This is basic enough to implement that I haven't written the code for that, and in any case using a function allows for future generalizing and modability.

```
numNodes = len(nodeList)
connected = np.zeros([numNodes,numNodes])
for i, n1 in enumerate(nodeList):
    for j, n2 in enumerate(nodeList[i:]):
        dist = calcDistance(n1, n2)
        if dist < e:
            connected[i,j] = 1
            connected[j,i] = 1
```